# WatchConnectivity transferFile method not working

Tags: ios, swift, watchos-2, watchconnectivity

I am attempting to transfer an image downloaded from facebook but for some reason my transferFile method has stopped working. The same code seemed to be working an hour ago and I cannot find what I have changed in order to cause it to stop working.

I am not getting an error from the delegate method nor is my log being called on the watch's side.

Here is how I am downloading my image and transfering.

```
func downloadImageToFile(urlString : String, completion: (NSURL?, NSError?) -> Void) {

        let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
        let session = NSURLSession.init(configuration: config)
        let imageURL = NSURL(string: urlString)

        session.downloadTaskWithURL(imageURL!, completionHandler:{(locationURL : NSURL?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) in

            if (error != nil) {
                print("Error: " + (error?.description)!)
                completion(nil, error)
            }
            else {
                if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: locationURL!) {

                    let documentsDirect = self.documentDirectory()
                    let saveLocation = documentsDirect.URLByAppendingPathComponent("GCD.png")

                    let saveWasSuccessfull : Bool = data.writeToURL(saveLocation, atomically: true)

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{

                        if (saveWasSuccessfull) {
                            print("Save Was Successful")
                            completion(saveLocation, nil)
                        }
                        else {
                            completion(nil, error)
                        }
                    })
                }
                else {
                    print("Data Download Error")
                }
            }
        }).resume()
    }

func documentDirectory() -> NSURL {

        let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
        let urls = fileManager.URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
        if let documentDirectory: NSURL = urls.first! as NSURL {
            return documentDirectory
        }
    }
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
 let downloader = WebImageDownloader()
                        downloader.downloadImageToFile(string, completion: { (transferLocation, error) in
                            if (error != nil) {
                            }
                            else {
                                self.session.transferFile(transferLocation!, metadata: nil)
                            }
                        })

func session(session: WCSession, didFinishFileTransfer fileTransfer: WCSessionFileTransfer, error: NSError?) {

        if error != nil {
            print(error?.description)
        }
        else{
            print("Finished File Transfer Successfully")
        }
    }
```

**Watch**

```
func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveFile file: WCSessionFile) {

    print("File Recieved on Watch")
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { [weak self] in

        if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: file.fileURL) {
            self?.photos.append(data)
            self?.updateTable()
        }
        else {
            print(file.fileURL)
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas what is going on here? I have no errors logging to work with anything.

Comment: Don't do a `dispatch_async` inside the delegate callback on the watch.  The system deletes the file once your method returns so you either need to move it or get the data synchronously before then.  That wouldn't fix your issue if the method isn't getting called at all though

Comment: are you sure that `self.session` in this line `self.session.transferFile(` references an activated session?